# How to enlarge a map in R?

Tags: r, geospatial

I'm new here and this is my first question :) I'm gradually improving my R skills, especially geospatial ones. Usually I'm trying to solve all issue via google but this time I wasn't lucky and need to turn to you. Any idea how to enlarge the map attached? I've tried with xlim and ylim but it didn't work. My code:

```
*mapa<-plot(st_geometry(dataeu_map))+
choroLayer(x = dataeu_map, var = "Zmiana",
breaks=c(-6,-3,0,3,6,9,12,15,18),
col = carto.pal(pal1 = "red.pal",n1=2,pal2="green.pal",n2=6),
legend.title.txt="Zmiana w %", legend.title.cex = 1.2,legend.values.cex = 1)+
layoutLayer(title="Zmiana liczby ludności państw Europy w latach 2013-18 r.",
scale=FALSE,frame=FALSE,tabtitle=TRUE,postitle="center")*
```

I'd be very grateful if you could help me move forward.

Best regards,
Kris

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ARj4.jpg)

Comment: Look at the manual page for `par`, in particular the `mar=` variable which lets you set the outer margins of the plot. That will let you get rid of some of the white space around the plot.

Comment: Thank for reply. I've tried but it doesn't trim the picture. It's just moving it on the plot screen. It worked when used that xlim&ylim: "plot(st_geometry(eu_map),xlim=c(-12,44),ylim=c(35,70))". But when I connect it with data and do what I typed above (plot()+chorolayer(), it doesn't work again...

Comment: Is your goal to produce this map on the display window in R Studio? If you are producing the map for a publication, print it to a device (pdf, tif, svg, png, etc) in the format you need at any size you want.

Comment: Ok, I got it (with someone's help)! This is the code that I used to trim the map: "range<st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = -12, xmax = 46, ymax = 72, ymin = 35),
 crs = st_crs(map)))" and then: "map2 <- st_intersection(map, range)".